# I can't generate getters and setters with lombok

Tags: java, eclipse, lombok

I am developing a gradle project please take a look at my **build.gradle** :

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '1.5.7.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'

group = 'com.support.wizard'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

def swaggerVersion = "2.7.0"

dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security')
    compile('org.springframework.security.oauth:spring-security-oauth2')
    compile('org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-mail')
    compile group: 'com.sun.mail', name: 'javax.mail', version: '1.5.2'
    compile ("io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:${swaggerVersion}")
    compile ("io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:${swaggerVersion}")
    compile("mysql:mysql-connector-java:6.0.6")
    compileOnly('org.projectlombok:lombok')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}
```

I am using eclipse neon. I refresh gradle project but It's not generate  getters and setters for my entities.

like :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class UserEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String email;

    private String username;

    private String password;

    private String phoneNumber;

    private String role;

    private String resetToken;

    private boolean enabled;
}
```

When use Eclipse's shortcut Ctrl + O  for search of methods and fields in a class I don't see the getters and setters of my class `UserEntity`
Please do you have an idea ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found a solution I downloaded lombo jar and double click on it for install it then I restarted my eclipse finally cleaned my  project

Answer (score 3):

For IntelliJ enable AnnotationProcessors:

Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Compiler > Annotation Processors > **Enable annotation processing**

Answer (score 2):

You need to install the Lombok plugin for Eclipse in order to see generated code within the IDE. The easiest way is to use the installer contained in any `lombok.jar` (even the ones found in your local Maven or Gradle cache); it is an executable JAR.